# Need a high latency, ultra low bandwidth data transfer technique the likes of Google Pub/Sub but inverse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, pull, reply, subscriber

I have an interesting IoT use case. For this example let's say I need to deploy a thousand IoT cellular displays. These have a single LED that will display information that will be useful to someone out in the world. For example a sign at the start of hiking trail that indicates whether the conditions are favorable. Each display needs to receive 3 bytes of data every 5-10 minutes.

I have successfully created a computer based demo of this system using a basic http GET request and cloud functions in the GCP. The "device" will ask for its 3 bytes every 10 minutes and receive the data back. The issue here is that the http overhead takes up 200+ bytes so the bandwidth usage will be high over cellular.

I then decided to try out Google cloud Pub/Sub protocol, but quickly realized that it is designed for devices transmitting to the cloud rather than receiving. My best guess is that each device would need its own topic, which would scale horribly?

Does anyone have any advice on a protocol that would work with the cloud (hopefully GCP) that could serve low bandwidth receive only devices? Does the pub/sub structure really not work for this case?

Comment: PubSub is also HTTP oriented. You need your own protocol, maybe UDP based, or TCP if you must have the ACK.

Comment: I think you are right, I did many hours of research, and the only thing I could come up with was a custom UDP protocol. I'm surprised there is no low bandwidth protocol out there. The cost of maintaining a cellular IoT product is astounding with current protocols. Do you happen to know a good way to deploy a UDP service? I made a simple one using a cloud VM on GCP. Is that the best method? I assume it likely won't scale well.

Comment: You can maybe have a look to low power protocols, such as lorawan or sigfox. It might required a hardware redesign, but that protocol are designed to be light in term of overhead (and power consumption)

Comment: Cloud Run or Cloud Functions doesn't support TCP or UDP communication. A VM or a container on GKE will be your hosting platform.